# How to hide a button with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button as follows:

```
<a href="#" onclick="AddRow();return false;" class="btnA">ADD</a>
```

Once I click the button, it adds a row to a #dataList1. Then I want it to be hidden. And I did following in Javascript;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function AddRow(){
var tr = '<tr>';
tr += '<td></td>';
tr += '<td><span class="br"><input type="text" id="grpNm" name="grpNm" value="" style="width:96%"/></span></td>';
tr += '<td><span class="br"><input type="text" id="grpExp" name="grpExp" value="" style="width:96%"/></span></td>';
tr += '</tr>';
    $('#dataList1').append(tr);
};

$('#AddRow').on('click', function(){
$('#AddRow').hide();
}); 
</script>
```

It adds the row, but after it, it does not hide the button. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: add `$('.btnA').css('display', 'none');`

Comment: I've removed the `<JAVASCRIPT>` from the beginning of your title. Don't put tags in the title. (Do you see anyone else putting tags in the title?)

Comment: I'm curious why $('#AddRow').on('click', function(){
$('#AddRow').hide();
});  is not working??

Comment: Also, if you're using jQuery (and you clearly are), include the `jquery` tag on the question.

Comment: try $('#AddRow').style.disply="none"

Comment: Also note that if you call AddRow more than once, you're creating an invalid DOM: You cannot have multiple elements with the same `id` value (see `id="grpNum"` and `id="grpExp"` in the rows being added).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add id to input

**HTML**

```
    <a href="#" onclick="AddRow();return false;" class="btnA" id="AddRow">ADD</a>
    <div id="dataList1"></div>
```

And hide button after appending in AddRow function.

**JS**

```
function AddRow(){
var tr = '<tr>';
tr += '<td></td>';
tr += '<td><span class="br"><input type="text" id="grpNm" name="grpNm" value="" style="width:96%"/></span></td>';
tr += '<td><span class="br"><input type="text" id="grpExp" name="grpExp" value="" style="width:96%"/></span></td>';
tr += '</tr>';
    $('#dataList1').append(tr);

    $("#AddRow").hide();
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4jtY/1/)

Comment: You are also adding the $('#AddRow').hide() inside AddRow() function. In that case, you don't need to add 'id' explicitly when you can refer button using its class.

Comment: Yes, "And hide button after appending in AddRow function.". I've edited my fiddle to be more clear.

Comment: My question is why you need to give id when that button can be referred by its class?

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no control with the id `AddRow`. You have to either give id or use class sector `$('.btnA').hide();`

```
<script>
function AddRow(){
var tr = '<tr>';
tr += '<td></td>';
tr += '<td><span class="br"><input type="text" id="grpNm" name="grpNm" value="" style="width:96%"/></span></td>';
tr += '<td><span class="br"><input type="text" id="grpExp" name="grpExp" value="" style="width:96%"/></span></td>';
tr += '</tr>';
$('#dataList1').append(tr);
$('.btnA').hide();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the button in `AddRow()` function itself:

```
function AddRow(){
  var tr = '<tr>';
  tr += '<td></td>';
  tr += '<td><span class="br"><input type="text" id="grpNm" name="grpNm" value=""  style="width:96%"/></span></td>';
  tr += '<td><span class="br"><input type="text" id="grpExp" name="grpExp" value=""   style="width:96%"/></span></td>';
  tr += '</tr>';
  $('#dataList1').append(tr);
  $('.btnA').hide();
};
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OHoHujaz/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Three Steps Problems:

1) Add this code inside AddRow() function:

```
$('#AddRow').hide();
```

2) Remove This event:

$('#AddRow').on('click', function(){

3) Add id AddRow in

```
<a href="#" onclick="AddRow();return false;" class="btnA">ADD</a>
```